# Thunderbird crashes while using Enigmail

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, enigmail

I am on thunderbird 68.4.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04 Lts. And I am using Enigmail 2.1.5 (20191231-1524) with gpg2 for encrypting and signing emails. However when I try to activate signing with enigmail while trying to compose a message Thunderbird crashes.

I have tried to look for a solution but of no avail. I am sorry if I am raising an already solved issue.

Update: I am also unable to access the error logs of Enigmail. I have tried as mentioned [here](https://www.enigmail.net/index.php/en/faq?view=topic&id=15#faqLink_6https://).

Terminal log:

```bsh
1579601806898   addons.xpi  WARN    Can't get modified time of /usr/lib/thunderbird/features/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net
Extension error: Error while loading 'jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi!/manifest.json' (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513 :: readJSON/</<@resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513:20
onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:9

1579601807148   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method startup on messagingmenu@mozilla.com: Error: Error while loading 'jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi!/manifest.json' (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)(resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513:20) JS Stack trace: readJSON/</<@Extension.jsm:513:20
onStopRequest@NetUtil.jsm:128:9
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/gContactSync@pirules.net.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/quickfolders@curious.be.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/tblatex@xulforum.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/cardbook@vigneau.philippe.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/sendlater3@kamens.us.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/sendlaterbutton@thunderbird-mail.de.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/{a62ef8ec-5fdc-40c2-873c-223b8a6925cc}.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}.xpi
[calBackendLoader] Using Thunderbird's builtin libical backend
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/gContactSync@pirules.net.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for gContactSync@pirules.net
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/tblatex@xulforum.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for tblatex@xulforum.org
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/quickfolders@curious.be.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for quickfolders@curious.be
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/sendlater3@kamens.us.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for sendlater3@kamens.us
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/sendlaterbutton@thunderbird-mail.de.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for sendlaterbutton@thunderbird-mail.de
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/cardbook@vigneau.philippe.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for cardbook@vigneau.philippe
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/{a62ef8ec-5fdc-40c2-873c-223b8a6925cc}.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for {a62ef8ec-5fdc-40c2-873c-223b8a6925cc}
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/zenith/.thunderbird/u5yu5yc9.default/extensions/{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for {e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}
prpl-gtalk: Error during SRV: Lookup failed.
console.warn: Overlays.jsm: Could not resolve 1 references Array [{}]
console.warn: Overlays.jsm: Could not resolve 1 references Array [{}]
console.warn: Overlays.jsm: Could not resolve 3 references Array [{},{},{}]
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 3476
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

Comment: There is nothing for us to go on here. If it crashes investigate the crash report or include it into the question. I suggest to start Tbird from command line and copy paste the error shown when it crashes.

Comment: I added the terminal log as you asked. There is an extension error at the top. but I don't know what it is for.

Comment: You have an extension installed that is not for your version of tbird. Probably Messaging Menu from what I see on the 2nd line of your log. Delete it and tbird will work again

Answer (score -1):

I use the same TB and Enigmail versions as above in Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit) latest version. When I start TB from the terminal and I try and send a message encrypted with Enigmail, here is the terminal output:

```
1584544087171   addons.xpi  WARN    Can't get modified time of /usr/lib/thunderbird/features/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net
Extension error: Error while loading 'jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi!/manifest.json' (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513 :: readJSON/</<@resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513:20
onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:9

1584544087385   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method startup on messagingmenu@mozilla.com: Error: Error while loading 'jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi!/manifest.json' (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)(resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513:20) JS Stack trace: readJSON/</<@Extension.jsm:513:20
onStopRequest@NetUtil.jsm:128:9
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/XXXX/.thunderbird/ua5a05bk.default/extensions/tbsortfolders@xulforum.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/XXXX/.thunderbird/ua5a05bk.default/extensions/ImportExportToolsNG@cleidigh.kokkini.net.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/XXXX/.thunderbird/ua5a05bk.default/extensions/tbsortfolders@xulforum.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for tbsortfolders@xulforum.org
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/XXXX/.thunderbird/ua5a05bk.default/extensions/ImportExportToolsNG@cleidigh.kokkini.net.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for ImportExportToolsNG@cleidigh.kokkini.net
1584544087799   tbsortfolders.folderPane    DEBUG   Init
1584544087799   tbsortfolders.folderPane    DEBUG   Add observer
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 12187
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

Hoping this can help somebody to diagnose the problem...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Better ask new question giving a reference to the current question.